# How to read values from an API using volley?

Tags: android, arrays, api, android-volley

I have a simple app tha make a call an API, base on the response I want to display some images on a fragment,
but I'm having a hard time trying to read the response.

Below is the code I'm using an a sample of the response.

By doing this I able to read the response, but don't know how to loop thru and make the logic if active or not.

> response.getJSONObject("sections");

```
public void propertySelector() { 
        String url = "myurl";

        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                try {
                    jsonObject = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(response));

                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("sections");
                   
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("TAG", "Error: " + error.toString());
            }
        });
        volleyRequest.add(request);
    }
}

sections: {
    Home: {
        active: true
    },
    Activites: {
        active: false
    },
    enabled: true, 
},
```

Comment: Are you getting JSONObject or JSONArray? Your example is showing JSONObject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that sections: {...} is the response

You're trying to read sections as a JSONArray but is an object, you have to read it like this:

```
jsonObject = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(response));
Iterator<String> sectionKeys = jsonObject.keys();
while(sectionKeys.hasNext()){
   String sectionKey = iter.next();
   if (sectionKey.equals("enabled")) {
      Boolean enabled = jsonObject.getBoolean("enabled");
      ...
   } else {
      JSONObject sectionObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject(sectionKey);
      Boolean active = sectionObject.getBoolean("active")
      ...
   }
}
```